# Down-Voting Answers Means Losing Rep?

Tags: feature-request, answers, downvotes

I just realized that down-voting answers will make you lose 1 rep every single time. There are new users every day and even more getting the ability to down-vote people (YAY! More people controlling our answer and question quality!). But it seems weird that we have to sacrafice our precious, hard-earned rep just to keep our answer quality up. There are really bad answers out there but there are little downvotes. If you can freely down-vote questions, the same should be for the answers. There are ***more*** answers than questions, so taxing us to control the quality millions to billions of answers seems awful and so wrong! **So my request is that we should not lose any rep for down-voting answers.** Currently we have to lose 1 rep per answer, and that amount could increase rapidly due to the vast amount of answers.

Comment: You don't get the vote down privilege until 125 rep ([docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)).  So no, there are not *new* users every day who are getting the ability to down vote people. There are users who have invested some work into the site's quality (even the association bonus isn't sufficient) before they can down vote.  I'll also point out, [I'm not complaining about the rep cost](http://stackoverflow.com/users/289086/michaelt).

Comment: I am not asking why. I am just asking for a feature to remove this rep loss that's all.

Comment: But your request doesn't indicate you understand why there is a rep loss in the first place.

Comment: I don't really care that much. I just simply follow the rules at SO.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn a little more about how the site works. Take your time to observe and learn for a while before jumping in making feature requests about a system you don't yet fully understand. Stack Overflow has been around for 6+ years to fine-tune all this.

Comment: Sorry. I will try to do that. I was just a little worried

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 1 reputation penalty is more of a mental thing than an actual loss of rep. In comparison to all of the other actions on the site (+10 for an upvote, +15 for accepted), 1 reputation is basically nothing.

The removal of 1 reputation is just in place to make sure that you downvote things for the right reasons. Otherwise, you could just go on a downvote rampage. Basically, it makes you think twice about downvoting.

And to be honest, how many posts are you downvoting that it's having a serious effect on your reputation? I certainly don't downvote more than 10 times a day, and most of those are on questions. I find that the problamatic posts are almost always questions. People will ask off-topic questions, or not put much work into them, or just dump code and ask us to fix them. Answers are almost always higher quality - the people writing answers are typically more experienced and have been around long enough to know how to write a good answer.

Comment: I am not the type of person who gets a lot of upvotes for my answers because the questions I answer are rarely viewed

Comment: @PythonMaster Well, your username is PythonMaster. Python is the 7th most popular tag on StackOverflow, with over 374,000 questions. Just keep answering questions, make sure that your answers are high quality, and the upvotes will come.

Comment: My friends encouraged my username to be that. I would prefer Pythonist. By the way, how do you change your username?

Comment: @PythonMaster See this link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85820/276203. You'll find it in your profile, where it says "edit" in the tabs at the top.

Comment: @PythonMaster you can edit your profile information in your profile edit link.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/4052384 - note the "Display Name" field.

Comment: @PythonMaster: you can change your username in your profile, provided you haven't changed it too recently (30 days, IIRC).